# Split/Package Angular application

Tags: angularjs

I have an Angularjs Application on Node.js. I want to divide the whole applications into multiple small applications. Like I want to separate the common functionality from specific functionalities.

For example, I have Person Module, Actor Module, Doctor Module, Lawyer module. Person Module is being used by other Modules. All others are independent. All the modules have javascript files ( Controller and Service) and html files.

Currently, all the files are in one directory /folder. I want to keep all these modules in different folders / applications. If I want Doctor App, I should be packaging Doctor Module and Person Module into one Application. If I want Lawyer App, I should be packaging Lawyer and Person modules into one application.

In Version Control, how do I separate them? and how do I get them and package them based on what I want?

The question is essentially how to separate the angular code and package it based on what I need?

Any clues/tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your build tool. If you use Grunt or Gulp then you can easily merge your JS files into one by defining a pattern of source files. You could define to merge all the files in the Person or Doctor app folder.